# Integer/float calculation in numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have the code:

```py
A = np.array([[1,2,3,4],
              [1,3,2,4],
              [1,5,1,2],
              [1,2,2,1],
              [2,1,1,3]])

A[1:4,2] = A[1:4,2] - [2.3,2.2,2.1]
```

this modifies the sub-column to still be an array of integer, however if I do this:

```
x = np.array([[3,3,3,3],[2,2,2,2]])
y = np.array([[2.2,2.1,2.1,2.1],[1.2,1.2,0.2,0.3]])
z = x-y
```

then it is a float stored in z, what is the explanation for this? How does the internal casting work? Thank you!

Also, is the best solution to this to declare A = A.astype(float)? is there better/recommended methods?

Comment: Add keyword argument `dtype=np.float` to `np.array()`. This tells NumPy the array is indeed of float64 type though all numbers are integers.

Comment: One way of other `A` needs to be float dtype if you want to put float values in it.  Exactly how you do that doesn't matter much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Data Types](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.types.html), Numpy tries to preserve the type of the operands in the same way Python does. If you are doing an operation with integers that would result in integers (say summing) the result is integer. If you are mixing it with floats, the result will be float.

```py
a=3
print(type(a)) # <class 'int'>
b=2.9
print(type(b)) # <class 'float'>
print(type(a-b)) # <class 'float'>
```

With numpy it is the same. You can also cast your results using the `astype` method. Also during array creation you can specify the type with the `dtype` parameter

```py
a = np.array([1, 2])
print(a.dtype) # int64
b = np.array([1.1, 2.2])
print(b.dtype) # float64
print((b-a).dtype) # float64
c = (b-a).astype('int64')
print(c.dtype) # int64
d = np.array([1.1, 2.2], dtype='int64')
print(d.dtype) # int64
```